# Chainage plugin (Qchainage) not starting at the beginning of line

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qchainage

Chainage points not beginning at the start of each line - using QGIS 2.18.2 and Qchain plugin I select the lines layer I'm working with, adjust chainage to every 10m and select "show label". 
Can anyone advise what steps I might be missing or I need to take to correct.

[image]

Comment: You are dealing with multipart polyline, even if it looks continuous single line. In ArcGis I'd use multipart to single part tool. Surely you have similar one in Qgis.

Comment: FelixIP - thanks for the suggestion. The layer was generated by dissolving line segments into single line features and I had run the multipart to single part algorithm and the simplify geometries function without any success.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to lie with the direction of the segments that were dissolved in the original layer to form the merged layer. Some of them are pointing in the "wrong" direction[image]

Comment: Unfortunately changing the "direction" of the segments did not resolve the issue the vertices within each segment are not being dissolved and reordered and the Qchainage plugin picks up the 1st vertex and works from there.